Viewing Photos in a LibreOffice Calc file
I have inserted an image into a cell in a LibreOffice Calc file.
What do I have to do to be able to click on that image to view it in original size, and then the same for images in other cells?

Can you specify how you inserted the image into the cell? Can you list a few things you've tried so far and the resources you've used to research this?


Right-click on a single image, or,
If there are multiple images:

Shift-left-click to select only those desired, or
Left-click to select one image, then press CtrlA to select all images,


Then right-click an image in the selection to show the context menu.
Select Original size from the context menu.



I was hoping there was a quick one click to see in original rather than right click the another on original and the another to fit. My ideal would be the ability to be able to quickly see each picture. Thank you for your input and I hope there is a easier solution

@Don, you can select all images att once -- see edited answer.
